# How can I start fluidsynth playback with certain cc commands specified from the very start?

Tags: fluidsynth

If I run `fluidsynth` from the terminal

```
fluidsynth soundfont.sf2 midifile.midi
```

I am then able to write [control change commands](http://www.midi.org/techspecs/midimessages.php) in realtime to alter the playback. For example,

```
cc 1 7 0
```

sends a CC#7 message (channel volume) to channel 1 with a value of 0, meaning that the volume on channel 1 is set to 0.

Now, I would like to specify a bunch of these cc commands when calling `fluidsynth`, meaning that the channel volumes are set *before* playback starts (in turn meaning that I can output my desired mix to an audio file, which is my end goal here).

When reading the `fluidsynth` [manual](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/fluidsynth/wiki/UserManual), I find the following option:

```
-f, --load-config
    Load command configuration file (shell commands)
```

I'm guessing this is what I want to use, since control change events, further down in the `fluidsynth` manual, is listed under MIDI MESSAGES, which in turn is listed under SHELL COMMANDS. However, the manual doesn't give me much to go on here (the quoted passage is the only thing that's being said about this option; no examples, no nothing). I've tried reading up on [configuration files in UNIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_file) without being able to resolve anything.

I've tried making a file called `config`, filled it with a bunch of cc commands, like so:

```
cc 0 7 0
cc 1 7 0
cc 2 7 0
```

and then trying to load it by using

```
fluidsynth -f config soundfont.sf2 midifile.midi
```

but this approach doesn't do anything (fluidsynth doesn't report any error either).